# Tycho raises error that Eclipse IDE does not: Cannot refer to a non-final variable

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

[Eclipse Tycho](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/), a Maven plugin for building Eclipse plugins, raises a compile error that Eclipse IDE does not: *Cannot refer to a non-final variable urlString inside an inner class defined in a different method*

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:0.19.0:compile (default-compile) on project org.nodeclipse.ui: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] D:\Workspaces\Nodeclipse-DEV\nodeclipse-1\org.nodeclipse.ui\src\org\nodeclipse\ui\preferences\NodePreferencePage.java:[93]
[ERROR] URL url = new URL(urlString);
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Cannot refer to a non-final variable urlString inside an inner class defined in a different method
[ERROR] 1 problem (1 error)
```

The fix is trivial, simply add a `final`.

However I was wondering why the compilation with Tycho is different from Eclipse IDE?
Both have Java version set to 1.6 (see in [pom.xml](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/pom.xml#L184-L185))

Details on the project setup:

- .project and .classpath are [committed](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.ui)
- .classpath has [JavaSE-1.6](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/.classpath#L4) and I can see that in Eclipse as "JRE System Library [JavaSe-1.6]" folder.
- [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
  declares `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6`

However I did run over JVM 8 and I had workspace default to 1.8

Comment: SO question may not significantly change in scope anyway, so it is not necessary to mark edits with EDIT or UPDATE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that you have configured Eclipse to build for Java 6. For me, the JDT allows access to non-final variables in closures if and only if I set the JDK compliance level to 1.8. So you apparently have the wrong compiler settings in Eclipse.

---

Obviously it is error-prone if you have to keep Eclipse and Tycho settings in sync manually. Therefore, the recommendation is to configure the compiler settings for both via the **execution environment**:

1. Declare `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6` in all plug-in manifests. (The PDE doesn't support configuration inheritance, so you unfortunately have to do this in every plug-in project.)
2. If your project has the `.project` files checked in, make sure that all projects have project-specific compiler settings enabled, and that the option *Use compliance from execution environment on the Java Build Path* is selected. This setting is stored in `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`, so this file also needs to be checked in. You can omit this step if don't have the `.project` files checked in but use m2eclipse to import your projects.
3. Remove any `tycho-compiler-plugin` `source`&`target` configuration, and the `target-platform-configuration` `executionEnvironment` configuration, if present. This makes sure that the execution environment from the bundle manifest is used to determine the compiler settings in Tycho. (See the [Tycho Execution Environments](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Execution_Environments) configuration for details)

Comment: I updated questions with details. Changing project properties just adds `.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file with 1.6 param.
I would like to keep tycho to override source&target configuration.  Is it Eclipse bug that I see project as using 1.6 but actually it is using 1.8 level?